# How do you build a simple low cost single photon detector?

Tags: experimental-physics, photons

Rather than buying a 4K-10K single photon detector, I was wondering if there were simple ways to build a simple single photon detector, of decent quality...

Comment: Perhaps you may want to talk to Jeremy O'Brien!

Comment: At ionizing energies, you build a Geiger-Müller tube. At optical or UV energies a PMT or MCP if you can tolerate the quantum efficiency, or use a solid state detector to get a better QE. The real problem here is that you have not specified the design task nearly well enough to get an answer.

Answer (score 5):

Geiger mode Avalanche Photo Diodes will do single photon counting at a few MHz with a little cooling.

20 years ago they were about $300 each from RCA with a fibre pigtail included ( see http://academic.research.microsoft.com/Publication/2600562/a-new-silicon-avalanche-photodiode-photon-counting-detector-for-astronomy for a simple counting/drive circuit)